# Domino Java Agent with jars attached to Design Element causes OutOfMemory errors

Tags: java, lotus-notes

An application I have uses Java Agents with need large jar Libraries (the biggest one is PDFBox - all in all 11MB). They were running for 3 years without any issue with the jars in jvm/lib/ext.

During an upgrade to Domino 9.0.1FP6 the administrator forgot to reinstall the jars in jvm/lib/ext - with obvious repercussions. (Such an annoyance that IBM just completely replaces the whole jvm sometimes without being gentle to the jars)

Upon request, I changed the code by including the jars directly into the Java Agents. Things worked well for 2-3 days, and now we're getting OutOfMemory errors.

As far as I understand it, the jars get loaded onto the Java Heap when the agents get started, but the garbage collection is working slower than the continuous loading of the jars into the heap. I couldn't find any precise documentation by IBM on this matter.

We've increased JavaMaxHeapSize in the notes.ini of the servers but that didn't bring the expected results.

I'm dismissing the possibility that I have forgotten a recycle() in my code because it run beforehand with no memory leaks for three years.

I have thought of the possibility of running a separate Agent that checks total memory usage and then runs Sytem.gc() but I'm not convinced since I have no guarantee that the garbage collector will actually fire.

Apart from the obvious move of putting back the jars in jvm/lib/ext, is there an alternative that I haven't considered?

And is there anywhere some sort of documentation about how these classes get loaded into the Heap, and whether there's a possibility that the jars erroneously are not recognized as being garbage-collectible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a memory leak bug - see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO49880 for details.

You need to go back to placing the jar files in jvm/lib/ext.

Comment: Cheers Per. What bollocks.

Comment: Per, I was wondering - does that affect as well jars that are put into a Java Script Library?

Comment: It affects agents only - so not XPages. I'm sure it affects agents using script libraries with jars too.

Comment: I've set up my java code to be compiled into a jar with an ant script. I found it to be the 'neatest' solution (i.e. the whole java development is made outside DDE). This implies, however, that you can't attach a jar anywhere in the domino database for fear of memory leaks, no?

Comment: I should then simply import the .java classes

Comment: Simon, This means that one can't ever do Import/Archive in Java Agents or in Java Script Libraries, no?