# Is the memory leak bug still present for java agents using imported .jars in Domino 12?

Tags: lotus-domino

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008580/domino-java-agent-with-jars-attached-to-design-element-causes-outofmemory-errors) that attaching .jar files to domino agents causes a memory leak and the solution is to add them to jvm/lib/ext and restart the jvm. However I understand that putting them in the /ext folder can cause some [security issues](https://domino-ideas.hcltechsw.com/ideas/DDXP-I-3) (see comments).

Is the memory leak problem still the case in Domino 12.0?

Would using the [OpenNTF Domino API](https://github.com/OpenNTF/org.openntf.domino) solve this issue?

Are there any long-term memory leak issues in just using .jars in the /ext folder?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the memory leak problem is still an issue in Domino 12.

BUT: There's a workaround. Set the following notes.ini to cache the agentloader objects and reuse them:

```
EnableJavaAgentCache=2
```

---

From SPR # BHUY8PRMKK:

> “The Product Development Team had developed a possible fix that
> mitigates the issue but the fix was of medium risk and it was decided
> not to submit the fix. As an alternative they have come up with a
> workaround. Set the following notes.ini, this will cache the
> agentloader objects and reuse them.“

Source: https://www.eknori.de/2021-03-20/java-agents-with-imported-jar-files/

Comment: That's useful! Thanks! Any view on the OpenNTF domino API? Is that worth the install?

Comment: OpenNFT Domino API (ODA) does not solve the memory leak issue but yes, ODA is worth the install in general for Java on Domino.

Comment: That's really helpful. Thanks once again.